# block &sa=U&ei= requests in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that is getting a lot of requests like this:

```
http://site/folder/url.html&sa=U&ei=c9hNU7aVDOy(and more gibberish)
```

I've added this to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)&sa=U /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work: the site still hands out 404 pages. (I've flushed the caches).

Help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it would have been fair to use `QUERY_STRING` to match query string parameters.
But since you don't have leading `?` it does not consider it as query string.

Your rule seems correct.
Anyway, it looks like it does not work as expected.

You can try the following alternative, which is working

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)&sa=U.*$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

---

EDIT: your rule is working the way you want, you only have to make your pattern more specific

```
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&sa=U /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an rule base on the query string (= GET parameters), you have to use a RewriteCond, you can't access them through a RewriteRule. So :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sa=U [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```